# How can I get the packet loss value in Python.subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, network-programming

I'm trying to get a packet loss value from ping
but it gives me `b'Bad value for option -c.\r\n'`.

How can I get the packet loss value?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

hostname = "8.8.8.8"
process = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-c','5',hostname],
stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Comment: What OS? `-c` is an option for Linux ping, but not for windows.

Comment: `ping -c <count>` is UNIX. Since you flagged this with `powershell` I assume Windows. That would be `ping -n <count>`

Comment: yea the os is windows, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Jordanm and Shmee, kindly do the changes accordingly, after that, you need to print the value of Packet Loss, List Comprehension will surely help.
You can do something like this -

```
packet_loss = float([x for x in stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n') if x.find('packet loss') != -1][0].split('%')[0].split(' ')[-1])
print("%s percent" % packet_loss)
#DO SOMETHING
```

Comment: thanks it works!!, But I had to change it from float to str.